# In django templates, how to dynamically update header section depending on a customized tag parameters in body section

Tags: python, django

I am building a Django listing app. to use it, a template should looks like this :

```
    {% load django_listing %}
    <html>
    <head>
    ...
    {% include "django_listing/header.html" %}
    ...
    </head>
    <body>
    ...
    {% render_listing data some_parameters %}
    ...
    {% include "django_listing/footer.html" %}
    </body>
    </html>
```

This template is directly used in a `TemplateView`. It is important to know that the user can define all parameters in the template, the listing is created on-the-fly in the custom `render_listing` tag thus `some_parameters` is only known in template side (not known at `TemplateView` side). The user only gives the data in the `TemplateView` context.

I want to dynamically declare some CSS and JS depending on the `some_parameters` values. I succeded to do that for JS in `{% include "django_listing/footer.html" %}`, but not for CSS because when rendering `{% include "django_listing/header.html" %}` the listing object has not been created yet.

Do you have an idea how to dynamically declare some CSS depending on the `some_parameters` ?
May be there is a way to postpone `{% include "django_listing/header.html" %}` rendering ?

Comment: "the listing object has not been created yet" what does this mean - the `render_listing` tag has a side effect that updates the parameters passed to it? Why not generate the listing in the view or generate it in a tag that passes it back to the context

Comment: I want to give the user the possibility to avoid touching his python code : just put the `render_listing` tag should be enough.

Comment: There's [django-sekizai](https://django-sekizai.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) if you want to be able to add CSS and JS in any included template

Answer (score 0):

Finally, the solution was to create a template tag for the header that renders the remaining before itself :

```
class ListingHeaderNode(template.Node):
    def __init__(self, nodelist):
        self.nodelist = nodelist

    def render(self, context):
        remaining_output = self.nodelist.render(context)
        tpl = template.loader.get_template('django_listing/header.html')
        tpl_output = tpl.render(context.flatten())
        return f'{tpl_output}\n{remaining_output}'


@register.tag(name="render_listing_header")
def do_listing_header(parser, token):
    nodelist = parser.parse()
    return ListingHeaderNode(nodelist)
```

Then I can use it instead of the include :

```
    {% load django_listing %}
    <html>
    <head>
    ...
    {% render_listing_header %}
    ...
    </head>
    <body>
    ...
    {% render_listing data some_parameters %}
    ...
    {% render_listing_footer %}
    </body>
    </html>
```